# Wrapper class returns null

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, wrapper-class

```
public class facebookuser{
    public String id;   //115020323424341
    public String name; //XXXX
    public cls_picture picture;
    public String birthday; //09/12/1990
    public String about;    //I beleive
    public class cls_picture {
        public cls_data data;
    }
    public class cls_data {
        public boolean is_silhouette;
        public String url; 
    }
    public static facebookuser parse(String json){
        return (facebookuser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, facebookuser.class);
    }
}

global class facebook_call
{
     public static String getownprofile(String token)
     {
            Boolean flag =false;
            Http http =new Http();
            HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture,birthday,about&access_token='+token);
            req.setmethod('POST');
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);             
           facebookuser objfacebookuser = new facebookuser();
           objfacebookuser=facebookuser.parse(res.getBody());
    }
```

**objfacebookuser** is Null. why ? Do i need to set properties in default constructor  ? 
Then How ?

**beginner in APEX**

```
 {
  "id": "112344322434",
"name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
"birthday": "09/12/1990",
"about": "I beleive.",
"picture": {
"data": {
  "is_silhouette": false,
  "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13658929_1039496126116440_8074761312212223685568213_n.jpg?oh=24a1c83a6417dd176bc5c134637a0d1b&oe=58B47A02"
 }
}
}
```

**debug log**

`16:26:58:430 USER_DEBUG [54]|DEBUG|facebookuser:[about=null, birthday=null, id=null, name=null, picture=null]`

Comment: can you post sample response you got.

Comment: {
  "id": "112344322434",
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "birthday": "09/12/1990",
  "about": "I beleive.",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13658929_1039496126116440_8074761312212223685568213_n.jpg?oh=24a1c83a6417dd176bc5c134637a0d1b&oe=58B47A02"
    }
  }
}

Comment: When I tested parsing with your sample response it worked fine. It parsed well. 
`DEBUG|objfacebookuser facebookuser:[about=I beleive., birthday=09/12/1990, id=112344322434, name=XXXXXXXXXXXX, picture=cls_picture:[data=cls_data:[is_silhouette=false, url=scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/…]]]`

Comment: That Method is static . Is it the reason for being Null  ?. Heard about static that It runs in diffenrent context,

Comment: 16:26:58:430 USER_DEBUG [54]|DEBUG|facebookuser:[about=null, birthday=null, id=null, name=null, picture=null]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the request as **GET** Method It will return perfect output.